# What is the probability that each card will have a different number when 5 cards are dealt?

Tags: probability

If we choose 5 cards from deck of 52, and card numbers go from 1 to 13...
What is the probability that each card will have different number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know the sample space is 52 choose 5. Count the number of $5$ card hands that all have different numbers. You have a set of $13$ numbers, and you must choose $5$. Then, each card may take on one of four suits, so multiply $13$ choose $5$ by $4^5$, to obtain the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{52*48*44*40*36}{52*51*50*49*48}$$
The first draw is valid with probability $\frac{52}{52}$, afterwards there are $52-4$ valid cards of $51$ total remaining etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this can be-
You have cards numbered from 1 to 13.
You choose 5 numbers out of 13, i.e. (13**C**5).
Now each of the chosen number has 4 types. So pick 1 from each i.e. (4**C**1)
Total 5 cards drawn so (4**C**1)*5.

So final answer = (13C5)*[(4C1)*5]